# Unable to see menus and numbers in Java-based programs

Tags: windows-7, java

I have noticed that in MarvinSketch and Jmol, which are both Java-based chemistry programs, that the File menu (including the drop-down menu and the menu names), save file window, and all other windows associated with the programs have rendering issues with their appearance. See the screenshot below for examples of these rendering issues.

[image]

If it is relevant I am running 64 bit Windows 7 SP1. If any other pieces of information are required please don't hesitate to ask, just remember my technological abilities are limited so you'll probably have to explain everything step-by-step for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the version of Java I was using, it had a bug that has been fixed with the latest version of Java. Evidence for this fact was obtained when I installed MarvinSketch with JRE which comes with a bundled Java version (namely an old one without this bug) it corrected itself.